# Could you recommend some books on Lie algebra？

Tags: reference-request, lie-algebras

I am a pure maths student, and  want to go straight ahead, so I  decide to study Lie algebra on my own, and try my best to understand it from various points of view：differential equation, Lie group, representation theory,..

Could you provide some advice and recommend some books? Thanks a lot

Comment: Could you provide some information to why you will be doing this, as that will affect what sort of book will be the most useful.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The reason why you want to study Lie algebras can have a great impact on what books one would recommend. Do you want to study solely the algebraic side? With a view towards algebraic groups? As a second introduction to representation theory (after finite groups)? Or do you want to learn about Lie theory, i.e. Lie groups **and** Lie algebras?

---

Without more information, I would explain what I did when I wanted to learn about Lie algebras. For background, I'll just say that I was interested in algebraic groups, and later got interested in number theory and automorphic forms (and so I then had to go back and learn about Lie groups). I started with *Introduction to Lie algebras* by Erdmann and Wildon. This is very hands down, they assume right away that you are working over the complex numbers. You won't get quite far with this book (it covers the main definitions and gives the structure theorem for semisimple Lie algebras), but if you do the exercises, you will have a good foundation. Then I moved to Humphreys' *Introduction to Lie Algebras and Representation Theory* (which has already been mentioned and is the absolute best). It is more terse than Erdmann and Wildon, and the exercises are more difficult, but it covers more.

Then, you might want more heavy-duty stuff. That's when I went to *Lie Groups Beyond an Introduction* by Anthony Knapp. For this, you need some knowledge of topology and differential geometry, i.e. knowledge of smooth manifolds. But this is a very good book, and it covers a wide range of topics.

Answer (score 12):

James Humphreys - Introduction to Lie Algebras and Representation Theory ([link](http://books.google.com/books/about/Introduction_to_Lie_Algebras_and_Represe.html?id=mSD4DvUFa6QC))

Comment: And when you get to the classification of semisimple Lie algebras in Humphreys, I wrote a "big-picture" guide to the proof as an answer to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/427135/relation-between-root-systems-and-representations-of-complex-semisimple-lie-alge/ with references to Humphreys.

Comment: This is a horrible book for self-studying.

Answer (score 6):

This. Easy to read. You can read it like a Harry Potter storybook.

[http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Algebras-Springer-Undergraduate-Mathematics/dp/1846280400](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1846280400)

Comment: As a side-note, this is the Erdmann and Wildon book I mentioned in my answer, so I completely agree with this answer

Comment: I don't agree with this being like Harry Potter.

Answer (score 4):

Naive Lie Theory by Stillwell.

Answer (score 3):

These free notes by Alistair Savage are an excellent introduction (based on Stillwell's and Hall's books). A bit more advanced, yet inclusive of Stillwell.

http://alistairsavage.ca/mat4144/notes/MAT4144-5158-LieGroups.pdf

Comment: I had Alistair as a lecturer when I was an undergraduate student. I haven't read these notes specifically (and I didn't take Lie theory with him), but he's an excellent teacher.