# What is the best place to start learning Clifford and Lie algebras?

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, lie-algebras, clifford-algebras

I'm looking for good references for a self-study on Lie and Clifford algebras. I think (but I don't know for sure) that these algebras have some connections (maybe these are homomorphic algebras?) and, if this is the case, it would be nice if the reference discusses such connections.

**Note:** I don't have a very strong background in algebra, but I have in analysis. As far as I know, these algebraic objects usually can be studied/introduced using either a more algebraic approach (say, using modules, rings and so on) or a more analytic one (using linear algebra, say). Thus, a more analytic approach fits best in my needs.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Isn't linear algebra more ... algebraic?

Comment: hahaha well, i was just trying to explain my preferences to linear algebra. More algebraic here means what is taught in regular algebra courses.

Comment: For Lie algebras, see [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/474609/could-you-recommend-some-books-on-lie-algebra?noredirect=1&lq=1). Here we definitely use linear and abstract algebra, and almost no analysis in the beginning. This is different for Lie *groups*.

Answer (score 2):

It so happens that I have been looking into that very same question myself and have encountered resources that you will likely find useful.

1. [Geometirc (a.k.a. Clifford) Algebra Video Series](https://www.youtube.com/c/AlanMacdonald1/videos) by Prof. Alan Macdonald. Note: He also publishes a book (and has a support website for those taking his course). It starts with linear algebra and works up from there, including all the way up to advanced Calculus based upon Geometric (Clifford) Algebra.
2. [A Swift Introduction to Geometric Algebra](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=60z_hpEAtD8) [44:22 minute YouTube video].

I hope these references you find helpful and set you on the right course. Good luck!