# Is the the reverse implication true for the Root of a simple Lie algebra?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

While reading the book James E Humphreys: "Introduction to Lie Algebras and Representation Theory". I encountered the next proposition
[image]

I understand the proof, and I was wondering if the reverse argument is true (If $\Phi$ is an irreducible Root system, then $L$ is simple). I have been thinking on it, and I don't see any problem to say the contrary, but I have been unable to prove it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I am not completely certain I know what you mean by the reverse implication here, but I hitnk this should be answered by point 5. in my answer at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/427135/relation-between-root-systems-and-representations-of-complex-semisimple-lie-alge/

Comment: The reverse implication would be that given an ireducible root system, then the lie algebra is simple, which is exactly what you proved. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: In that case yes, this is exactly point 5. in my previous answer.